# gwteventservice using maven example

Tags: maven

I need help with gwteventservice library... Currently, I need to implement push notification for my gwt application. I have found a good library to use, but I got problem when using it with maven (because my existing gwt application using maven). I tried to add the dependency to my gwt project pom.xml, but it keep giving me error at my Eclipse IDE. The error message is :

> ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   de.novanic.gwteventservice:eventservice-rpc:jar:1.2.0:
>   UnresolvableModelException: Could not transfer artifact
>   de.novanic.gwteventservice:parent:pom:1.2.0 from/to remote-repos
>   (http://XXX.XX.XX.XX:8081/artifactory/remote-repos): No response
>   received after 60000

I am using artifactory for proxying with online maven repository. 
This is the maven dependency tag I have added to my existing gwt project :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.novanic.gwteventservice</groupId>
            <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.novanic.gwteventservice</groupId>
            <artifactId>eventservice</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.novanic.gwteventservice</groupId>
            <artifactId>eventservice-rpc</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.novanic.gwteventservice</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwteventservice</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Please help me anyone. Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that you're getting tells you that maven can't find the parent artifact which is the first artifact in the dependency snippet that you posted. The reason for this is that the parent artifact in Maven central only includes a POM with no jar.

Take a look at the [Maven docs](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#POM_Relationships) and you'll notice that, for dependency blocks in your POM, the default type is jar. So, since you didn't specify a type, maven is looking for a jar. Since there's no jar it correctly fails.

If you really want that pom, just add `<type>pom</type>`. However, it appears that you just need the gwteventservice jars. I would suggest removing the first dependency.

Comment: I have try to add <type>pom</type> to the first artifact that I have posted, but still get the same error message. I have tried to remove the first dependency too, but still get the same error too. Please kindly advice me. Thanks.

Comment: @user1696191 To test, I plugged your dependencies (with the type tag added) into maven pointed directly at maven central, and all dependencies were pulled down correctly. This would imply that there's something wrong with your artifactory. Try searching for the poms in the artifactory gui to see if proxying is actually working.

Comment: yes.. it work if I tried it in my private network which is not using proxy, and it working well.. guess I have to take a look at my proxy network.. Thanks jon :)